# IndexError: list index out of range - Can't get my txt file to save the output in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

I'm writing a program that is referring to two text files. One stores the list of currencies in a sentence and one stores the current value. I want it to only store the value of the currency in the sentence once, but then stores each order so it can be replaced on screen. E.g. Sterling, Euro (in one file). 1,1,2 (in the order file). I keep getting the error message 
IndexError: list index out of range

```
all_currency = []
value_of_currency = []

my_words_file = open("words.txt","r")
my_words_document = my_words_file.readline()
while my_words_document != "": 
        all_currency.append(my_words_document.strip())
        my_words_document = my_words_file.readline()
print("output of the words in the saved list:",str(all_currency))
my_words_file.close()
positions = ""
my_numbers_file = open("numbers.txt","r")
value_of_currency = my_numbers_file.readline().strip().split()
my_numbers_file.close()
for mynumbers in value_of_currency:
    positions += all_currency[int(mynumbers)]+" "

print("output of the positions in the saved list:",positions)
```

Comment: Which line is the IndexError on?  I'm assuming it's `positions += all_currency[int(mynumbers)] + ""`  Try printing out `int(mynumbers)` before that line and seeing what it says.

Comment: Could  you show us the TraceBack of the error?

Comment: Yes it's that line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Specifically, run the basic debugging on this: at least print out **all_currency** and **mynumbers** just before the error point.  We can't debug this for you, since you haven't provided a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you are mainly indexing the currency first. Since in you case there is only 2 currency that's why trying to get the third index eg. arr[2] giving this error.

Comment: How do I not index the currency first?  I don't want the word replicated in the text file. I thought you could do just have the word once, and then use each number position to link them together?

Comment: When I print the positions string before, nothing shows as the output list is empty at that point.

Comment: Error message is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Matt/Desktop/stack", line 16, in <module>
    positions += all_currency[int(mynumbers)]+" "
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Comment: Still getting:                 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Matt/Desktop/stack.py", line 30, in <module>
    positions += all_currency[int(mynumbers)]+" "
IndexError: list index out of range                                                                          I'd just like one file with  Sterling,Euro,Dollar and then the positions saying 0,1,1,1,1,2,3 so all words are used but only store than once.  I've just added you on linked in!

Comment: I think you are not getting my point, let me break it. 
In your case say you have 3 currency which are indexed in an array named "all_currency[]"  having the index no : 0,1,2. So, now if you try to read "all_currency[]" with a index value greater than 2 then error will occur.
My suggestion :  clear the concept on array indexing.  Also, As i said i am not clear what you want to achieve. give your desired output.

Comment: One file stores all words, however just for the first time. Eg. Euro, sterling, dollar. Then another file stores 1,2,2,3,3,1. So the idea being that the sentence can be recreated if it knows each word and the positions of them.

Comment: Well your problem is that you are trying to get the position of undefined currency. For, position value: 3 there is no currency defined. Hope you understand now.

Comment: Sent you a message on linked in.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_words(words_file):
return [word for line in open(words_file, 'r') for word  in line.strip().split(',')]

all_currency = read_words("a.txt")
print(all_currency)
value_of_currency =  read_words("b.txt")
print(value_of_currency )

positions = ""
for mynumbers in value_of_currency:
      positions += all_currency[int(mynumbers)]+" "
print("output of the positions in the saved list:",positions)

#a.txt file contains currency: "Sterling,Euro,Dollar" 
#b.txt file contains currency: "1,1,2"
```

I actually didn't  get what was your desired output but i fixed the error problem. As i said earlier if you need to make sure that the values do not cross index number. Hope you understand.

Comment: How would I get it to display: